# Unable to cast CheckBoxList.Items to a ListItem - Type or namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I want to concatenate the selected value of a `CheckedListBox` to a single comma-separated string and store it to a database, but this code gives me an error:

```
var items = from member in checkedListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
            where member.Selected == true
            select member.Value;

string mylist = String.Join(",", items);
```

Error:

> The type or namespace name 'ListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'ListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing platforms. `CheckedListBox` is a WinForms control, but [`ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a web control.

That's why it's displaying that error - you're not referencing `System.Web` and you don't have `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` at the top of your file. And even if you had all that, it wouldn't be the right thing to do anyway.

---

The `CheckedListBox` control already keeps track of checked and selected items for you.

To retrieve the checked items, use `CheckedItems` and cast the collection back to the type of data you populated it with originally:

```
var checkedItems = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<YourClass>();
```

If you actually wanted selected items (probably not), use `SelectedItems` instead:

```
var selectedItems = checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<YourClass>();
```

After casting the items correctly, the last part you have should work just fine (assuming it's a collection of strings or, if you're using your own class, that it overrides `ToString()`):

```
string myFlattenedList = String.Join(",", checkedItems);
```

Comment: Instead of `checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<YourClass>();`, it should be `checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<YourClass>();`. I believe.